Oracle Apex : FOS - Download Files (Plug-In)
`Hello people of apex I need some help,
What query or SQL code should I put in to retrieve the Blob content of a database table for use in downloading or previewing plugins? (I managed to do the same thing with temporary collections but it wouldn't work for me in this case)
Thank you`
